# Nested insertion in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Consider the following structure in MongoDB database in a collection called `programs`

```
{ "_id": "Program123",
  "versions" : {
                  "v1" : "First Version",
                  "v1.4" : "First version with changes"
               }
}

}
```

Suppose that I want to add a new version field  `v2.0 : "Improved version"` without having to repeat the information in the versions field (like I would do with `$set`) and I do not want to replace the current contents of the collection.

After insertion

```
{ "_id": "Program123",
  "versions" : {
                  "v1" : "First Version",
                  "v1.4" : "First version with changes",
                  "v2.0" : "Improved version"
               }
}

}
```

1. How can I do it in MongoDB?
2. Shall I use an array instead of a dict inside the document?

Comment: It would be a lot clearer what you want if you simply gave (well-formatted!) examples of before and after.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You are right! I have updated the question

Comment: just pull it into an object or something, update it with the new data, and just upsert it

Comment: Is there a more cost-effective solution? The one that I use now gets the object and then saves it again using `db.posts.save()`

Comment: Have you taken a look at $addToSet ? Its exactly what you need I believe. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet